# How Can I Pass Value Of Edittext From One Activity To Other in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to pass the value of an `EditText` in one activity to another activity on button press and use that value in my code. However, there is one more activity between those activities in which I don't want to use that value

My Activity1 has:

```
textOut = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ipadd);
Button ip = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ipad);
ip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    startActivity(new Intent("com.shaz.hello"));
}});
```

From the Activity1 the user goes to the Activity2

Activity2

```
if ( x ==10 ) {
    startActivity(new Intent("com.shaz.hello2"));
}
```

From the Activity2 the user goes to the Activity3

Activity3

Here I want to use that value as a String.

Comment: have you tried using `Intents`?

Comment: no i dont know how to use the intents in this case

Comment: @ShivamBansal Does the following answer solve your problem?

Comment: No The App stoped working after first activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is an another solution;
create one `Bean` class like this,

```
public class Bean {
    public static String value;

    public static String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public static void setValue(String value) {
        Bean.value = value;
    }
}
```

On `first Activity` set the `variable` in `Bean`.

```
Bean bean = new Bean();
bean.setValue("your value");
```

And get the `variable value` on last or any `Activity`

```
Bean bean = new Bean();
String yourValue=bean.getValue();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can using `putExtra()` and `getExtra()`, Add this in your current activity:

```
ip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        Intent mIntent = new Intent(currentActivity.this, hello.class);
        mIntent.putExtra("valuename", Integer.valueOf(textOut.getText.toString));
        startActivity(mIntent);
    }
}
```

To get result from last activity put this line after `onCreate()`:

```
int myValue = getIntent().getIntExtra("valuename", 0);
if (myValue == 10) 
{  
    Intent mIntent = new Intent(currentActivity.this, hello2.class);
    startActivity(mIntent);
}
```

***Edited***

You need to add your activities in android manifest file, e.g:

```
<activity android:name=".hello2"></activity>
```